# Why this simple code not working on JSfiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dolours/Yazpj/577/ I can't figure out what is the issue with this js fiddle! why alert not showing up?

```
<input type='input' name='name' id='name' value="test" class='required' />
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="test()"/>

function test()
{
var testvalues = $('#name').val();   
alert(testvalues);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set jQuery in the library option since you are using jQuery in your code. jsfiddle.net/Yazpj/578/

[image]